# Translate pager generated by ReactiveList

Tags: reactjs, reactiveui

I have a list generated with ReactiveList (v2.17) which contains a pager at the bottom. The pager is in English ("Prev", "Next"), but the site is in Dutch. How can I translate these buttons? 
I've found the labels in this file (/node_modules/@appbaseio/reactivesearch/lib/components/result/addons/Pagination.js, at the bottom) but these seem to be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Web_Beest you can make use of Custom Pagination as of now and define your Custom pagination.

Check the prop `renderPagination` over here: https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/v3/result/reactivelist/#props

Comment: Thanks, but alas: I'm using v2.17 (renderPagination is only available in v3).

Comment: Right you can follow the migration guide in order to migrate to v3